# How can I encrypt a file in React to be decrypted in Python using Fernet?

Tags: python, reactjs, encryption, fernet

How would I encrypt my file in the client side with React to be decrypted in the server side with Python fernet. Wouldn't my file in the client side need to be encrypted by fernet as well. is it possible?

Ive tried Fernetjs but it came up with a buffer error since I am using it with React and not Nodejs
Ive also tried cryptojs but it isnt using the same encryption algorithm as fernet, making it unable to decrypt on the file side